# Orientation of QR using Zbar python

Tags: python, opencv, orientation, qr-code, zbar

I am detecting QR code with zbar in python. Right now I am getting 4 points in detected qr code.

```
decodedObjects = pyzbar.decode(im)
```

However, I am getting 4 points but no information about orientation. I need fixed orientation.

My query images are:[image]

[image]

[image]

I want all of them to be like:[image]

How can i fix the orientation? Any suggestions? I am open to use anything other than zbar or use combination of zbar + other options to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use **OpenCV** and **pyzbar** to do this.

Use `decoded.rect` to crop the image and `decoded.orientation` to rotate the image.

`decoded.rect`returns the bounding box of QR Code, and `decoded.orientation` returns 5 types of `ZBarOrientation` class:

- **UNKNOWN**: when pyzbar are unable to determine orientation;
- **UP**: upright, read left to right;
- **RIGHT**: sideways, read top to bottom;
- **DOWN**: upside-down, read right to left;
- **LEFT**: sideways, read bottom to top.

In this example, we are using this image as **input**:

[image]

```
# Imports
import cv2 as cv
from pyzbar import pyzbar

# Open image with OpenCV
img_input = cv.imread(filename = 'image.jpg',
                      flags = cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

Note that when importing the images, we use the `flags = cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` parameter, because in **OpenCV** the default color mode setting is **BGR**. Therefore, to work with **pyzbar**, we need to convert the color mode pattern from **BGR** to **grayscale**.

Now we will use **pyzbar** to decode the image into **QR Code**, if any.

And then, we'll use `decoded.rect` to crop the image and `decoded.orientation` to rotate the image:

```
decoder = pyzbar.decode(img_input)

if len(decoder) != 0:
    for decoded in decoder:
        if decoded.type == 'QRCODE':
            # Get the bounding box location of the QR Code
            left, top, width, height = decoded.rect

            # Crop input image (add 10 pixels to each side)
            qrcode = img_input[top - 10: top + height + 10, left - 10: left + width + 10]

            # Rotate QR Code, if necessary
            if decoded.orientation is not None and decoded.orientation != 'UNKNOWN':
                if decoded.orientation == 'LEFT':
                    # Rotate by 90 degrees clockwise
                    qrcode = cv.rotate(qrcode, cv.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
                elif decoded.orientation == 'RIGHT':
                    # Rotate by 270 degrees clockwise
                    qrcode = cv.rotate(qrcode, cv.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)
                elif decoded.orientation == 'DOWN':
                    # Rotate by 180 degrees clockwise
                    qrcode = cv.rotate(qrcode, cv.ROTATE_180)
```

Now we can simply save the QR Code image with the following command:

```
            # Save image
            cv.imwrite('cropped_qrcode.jpg', qrcode)
```

And the output will be:

[image]

Important information taken from the **pyzbar** documentation:

> If you see orientation=None then your system has an older release of
> zbar that does not support orientation.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem or you believe it is the best solution. Please, up-vote and mark this answer as accepted! Thank you! If it doesn't solve your problem, let me know!